# Stripe - Connecting to Standalone Accounts

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We are building an Android application in which we want to use Stripe as a payments platform.

We found that this github (https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-stripe-connect) specifies how to integrate standalone Stripe accounts. The problem is that in the last step of authentication we are supposed to call

```
Stripe.apiKey = mSession.getAccessToken();
```

and while the documentation on a website says it's the command we should use, the android studio shows that it: "Cannot resolve symbol 'apiKey'".

The other problem we encountered is

`Account account = Account.retrieve();`

An `Account` class was changed to a `BankAccount` and right now there is no `retrieve` function for the `BankAccount` class.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Stripe Authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) doc,
`Stripe.apiKey` is use to store your API key for stripe request.

Replace

```
Stripe.apiKey = mSession.getAccessToken();
```

with

```
Stripe.apiKey = "[PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY]";
```

You can use `Account` class to add multiple Bank accounts.

Check [Managing multiple bank and debit accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-transfers#multiple-accounts)

```
Stripe.apiKey = PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY;
Account account = Account.retrieve(CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID, null);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("external_account", "btok_9CUaZTAdbT4G5z"); // ("account","tokenId")
account.getExternalAccounts().create(params);
```

I hope it's helps you.